# How to change the background color of Radscheduler

Tags: css, telerik

I have query regarding the radschedular. Currently i'm using the outlook skin for radschedular. I need to change only the background color from yellow to white. Which is having a yellow color currently. How to change the same to white. Could you guys please shed some light to me. I'm stucked up in an lion's den now.

Comment: I would very much like to help you, which is why I am asking for code. Right now you are basically asking me to go look at radschedular and find the background class/id and give it back to you. If you atleast show some code you are working with radschedular I could at least have something to work off of to help you.

Comment: OK. It was a huge code. Basically i should copy and paste .aspx,.cs and css code over here. That's the reason i didn't paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add below class into your style sheet.

```
.RadScheduler_Outlook .rsContentTable td
{
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: Ok Jayesh. I will add and let you know. Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: Hi Jayesh, Thanks a lot. Your code turned the yellow to white. But im facing different problem now. It's over-riding the entire page color. I could attached the screen shot, but i dont have enough points to post screen shot

Comment: Soo i would like to explain. In scheduler, we are displaying few slots as disabled which will be in a light blue color. Which means that adviser's non- working hours. For ex: Saturday and sunday. We were displaying those in light blue color. But if i apply your code, its over-riding entirely.Could you please suggest anything on this

Comment: Code im using in css for light blue color.                                                            /*.RadScheduler_Outlook .rsContentTable td {
background: white !important;
}*/

.DisabledSlot
{
    background: lightblue !important;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

Comment: Hi Jayesh, i was able to get the required color when i removed the "!important" from your code. Will that removal have any impacts when its moved to production???

Comment: if your code is working fine after removing ""!important"" then it would be good. its behave same in all environment(QA/UAT/PROD.